# Adding a new record with a self join in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a self join on an object "thing"

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base  
    has_many :children, :class_name => "Thing", :foreign_key => "parent_id"  
    belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Thing"    
end
```

When I view a Thing I want to provide a link to the new thing page to create a child object with the parent_id populated with the id of the current Thing, so I thought I would use this

```
<%= link_to 'New child thing', new_thing_path(@thing) %>
```

but that doesn't work as the default action is to the GET method in the controller which can't find the :id in the params with

```
@thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
```

so the question is;

a) should I have a new controller for children or;
b) is there a better way to send the param of the parent_id through to the GET method in the Thing controller

Thanks in advance

Heath.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to create a new Controller for this purpose. You could also do it with some additional routes and actions in your existing Controller. If you already have a Thing controller mapped as a resource, you could add additional routes like this:

```
map.resources :things, :member => { :new_child => :get, :create_child => :post }
```

which will give you two additional routes:

```
new_child_thing     GET   /things/:id/new_child(.:format)
create_child_thing  POST  /things/:id/create_child(.:format)
```

Then you can add those two actions to your controller and handle the creation in them

```
def new_child
  @parent_thing = Thing.find(params[:thing_id])
  @thing = Thing.new
  ...
end

def create_child
  @parent_thing = Thing.find(params[:thing_id])
  @thing = Thing.new(params[:thing])
  @thing.parent = @parent_thing
  if @thing.save
    render :action => :show
  else
    render :action => :new_child
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`new_thing_path(:parent_id => @thing.id)`

And in the new action:

`parent = Thing.find params[:parent_id]`

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to 'New linked thing', new_thing_path(:Parent_id=>@thing.id) %>
```

and in the controller

```
def new
    @parent = Thing.find(params[:Parent_id])
    @thing = Thing.new
    @thing.parent_id = @parent.id
    respond_to do |format|
       format.html # new.html.erb
       format.xml  { render :xml => @organizr }
    end
 end
```

I guess my real question should have been how do I add parameters to a GET in Rails!